# How can I host a spring project in Windows IIS using tomcat?

Tags: java, windows, spring, tomcat, iis

I am new spring developer . I don't know how to host a spring project in Windows IIS using tomcat. My OS is windows server 2012

Comment: You can use IIS as the proxy for Tomcat. Reed more [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html)

Comment: HttpPlatformHandler is the IIS module you should install and enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I have deployed my spring project on tomcat using this link :
[Site for hosting spring project in tomcat](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-on-tomcat)

Then I have used BonCode connector to connect IIS and Tomcat.

[How to connect IIS and tomcat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVKiNAkhav8)